# what is the diff. between "->" and "=>" in php?

Tags: php

What are the uses of `->` and `=>` in PHP.
I have been trying the same since long time.Please do someone answer with examples.

```
$data['student_last_name'] = $this->input->post('student_lastname');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is used to access object property and `=>` is used to assign value to array key.

Example:

```
$name = $person->name;

$newArray = array(
    "name" => "John"
)
```

Comment: @KLP don't forget to accept the answer so that it will help others too

Comment: k sagar...hw to do that

Comment: @KLP take a look at top left corner of the my answer below down arrows you will find tick mark...